# SSRS Error can not access the Report manager

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportingservices-2005, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

Recently changed the windows password of the machine ,where the ssrs installed.All the services are running on the built-in account.

when trying to access the report server using the web-browser,it shows an error user does not have required permissions. Verify that sufficient permissions have been granted and Windows User Account Control (UAC) restrictions have been addressed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick Fix: 
Right click the browser and Run as Administrator. 
Then browse to the Report Url.

(Assuming You got that error because of UAC restriction).